# facebook login: How to redirect to a specific URL after login in

Tags: facebook-login

I have the following code in my html:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" scope="email,user_checkins,user_events,friends_checkins">Login with Facebook</div>
```

How do I specify a callback URL?  I want to redirect to a URL that then stores the returned auth token and other details.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `onlogin="..."` to your DIV you can specify a function to execute after login, for example:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" scope="email,user_checkins,user_events,friends_checkins" onlogin="alert( 'Logged In' );">Login with Facebook</div>
```